# In python, how do I find the sum of values in a dictionary? Where each key has multiple values

Tags: python, dictionary

My data is tab delimited and looks like this:

```
Name   Count    Sample
Dog    .0001    1
Dog    .00003   1
Dog    .0001    2
Cat    .0004    1
Cat    .0002    1
Cat    .0003    2
Cat    .0002    2
```

After i define my variables unid as the first column merged with the 3rd column (ex Dog_1) and num as the Count for that line, i append each num into a dictionary under the unid (using Python 2.7), like so:

```
for line in K:
        sp = line.split("\t")
        name = sp[0]
        unid = sp[3][:-2] +"_"+ sp[0]
        num = int(Decimal(sp[1]))
        if not dict1.has_key(unid):
            dict1[unid] = []
        dict1[unid].append(num)
```

I try to sum it with this:

```
dictTot = sum(dict1.values())
```

But i get this error message:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

How can I sum these values such that I can retrieve `Cat_1: .0006, Cat_2: .0005`  etc?

Sorry everyone, as I know my ? is not great. But as stated by Jacob below, 
"dictTot = sum(sum(value) for value in dict1.values())" sums all of the sums, but what I am looking for is to sum each group of values under each key independently so I can find out how many Cats there are in sample 1 and so on.  Perhaps sum is not right for this?  Sorry, as evident I am not a Python extraordinaire.

Comment: Could you provide the contents of the dictionary, ie what you'd get if you printed `dict1`

Comment: `int(Decimal('.0001'))` is 0. All your sample values will be 0.

Comment: `sp[3]` is out of index.

Comment: How can this part  `unid = sp[3]` work?.. there are only 3 columns, shouldn't the max index be `2`?

Comment: Err, can someone edit this - it's now missing data examples and is coming up as H's for html elements...

Comment: Yes, yes, sorry i tried to simplify it for the question and made some mistakes.  should be sp[2], as for the value being 0, perhaps this is better num = Decimal(sp[1])  however to sum you need to define the input as an integer correct?   Nonetheless, the same error message arises

Comment: No, Decimal can "sum" itself and return a Decimal

Comment: `int(Decimal(sp[1]))` or `int(float(sp[1]))` will ALWAYS be 0 with the example data.

Comment: folks, I don't understand why such a post would get so many downvotes. It has complete data file, his/her own code snippets, and well-defined purpose (plus Vince is a newcomer, I would give him/her a big thumb-up rather than a downvote), so please at least explain your downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I basically rewrote the whole thing...

```
K = "Dog    .0001    1\n  Dog    .00003   1\n  Dog    .0001    2\n  Cat    .0004   1\n  Cat    .0002    1\n  Cat    .0003    2\n  Cat    .0002    2"
dict1 = {}
for line in K.split("\n"):
    sp = line.split()
    name = sp[0]
    unid = "_".join([sp[0] , sp[2][-2:]])
    num = float(sp[1])
    if not dict1.has_key(unid):
        dict1[unid] = [num,]
    else :
        dict1[unid].append(num)
print(dict1)
dictTot = sum([sum(x) for x in dict1.values()])
print(dictTot)
```

the final dict is

```
{'Dog_2': [0.0001], 
 'Dog_1': [0.0001, 3e-05], 
 'Cat_1': [0.0004, 0.0002], 
 'Cat_2': [0.0003, 0.0002]}
```

the sum is

```
0.00133
```

the values are lists, so you want to loop them to sum individually.

**EDIT**

apparently now you want "Cat_1: .0006, Cat_2: .0005 etc", so upon `dict1`, you can do

```
for key in dict1.iterkeys():
    dict1[key] = sum(dict1[key])
```

now `dict1` becomes

```
{'Dog_2': 0.0001, 
 'Dog_1': 0.00013, 
 'Cat_1': 0.0006, 
 'Cat_2': 0.0005}
```

Comment: perfect!  Wow thanks for seeing thru the unpurposefully placed fog

Comment: @Vince haha, I like your description, glad that the fog is not as thick as the thunderstorm outside my window. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

That isn't how `sum` works. You're trying to get an integer (or numeric value type) by "adding" a bunch of lists, so the built-in function freaks out. Try this instead:

```
dictTot = sum(sum(value) for value in dict1.values())
```

That will sum all the sums, which is what you want (I think).

**EDIT**

Apparently you want to sum all the values in each element of the list. For that purpose, you can use a [dictionary comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/):

```
dictTot = {key:sum(l_values) for key, l_values in dict1.items()}
```

Comment: Sorry everyone, as I know my ? was not great.  But as stated by Jacob, "dictTot = sum(sum(value) for value in dict1.values())" sums all of the sums, but what I was looking for was to sum each group of values independently so I can find out how many Cats there are in sample 1 and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In order to sum all the values, you must first join all the lists together into one iterable that `sum()` can process. Here are two ways to do this:

```
dictTot = sum(sum(dict1.values(), []))
```

And the slightly more verbose, but more readable:

```
from itertools import chain
dictTot = sum(chain.from_iterable(dict1.values()))
```

`sum()` actually takes two arguments. The second argument, `start` defaults to `0`. Hence the error message you're getting about adding an `int` to `list`. In essence, it's doing this: `0 + [1, 2, 3] + [1, 2]...`. In my first example, I set the default start value to an empty list. The result is a single list. Now that I have all the values in a single list, I can `sum()` the result to obtain the answer.

**EDIT**

In response to your update:

You can do this with a generator expression:

```
dictTot = {key: sum(value) for key, value in dictTot.items()}
```

or if you are using < Python 2.7:

```
dictTot = dict((key, sum(value)) for key, value in dictTot.iteritems())
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

`dict((k,sum(v)) for k,v in dict1.iteritems())`

yea, change the `int(Decimal('.0001'))` and use a defaultdict

+1 for a question with downvotes and then four answers that missed the oneliner answer

**EDIT** oops I missed that @Joel Cornett had it so props there too

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
d={}
for line in K:
   sp = line.strip().split()
   unid = sp[0]+"_"+sp[-1] 
   num = decimal.Decimal(sp[1])
   d.setdefault(unid,[]).append(num)      

print({k:sum(v) for k, v in d.items()})
```

Prints:

```
{'Dog_1': Decimal('0.00013'), 
 'Cat_2': Decimal('0.0005'), 
 'Cat_1': Decimal('0.0006'), 
 'Dog_2': Decimal('0.0001')}
```